# IPv4 Header Format

Tags: ip, tcp

Только начал в эту тему вливаться, и никак не пойму один момент: почему в структуре IPv4 Header Format говорится, что "минимальное количество слов для второго составляющего (IHL) равно 5, а максимальное - 15".
Объясните, откуда взялась эта цифра? 
Под IHL выделено 4 бита, и они отвечают за количество слов. Но это мне ничего не сказало.

Comment: Минимальный заголовок - 20 байтов, максимальный - 60 (плюс опций от 0 до 40 байт). Если считать в dword (те, которые по 32 бит штука, и называть их "слово") - то от 5 до 20.

Comment: Цифра 5 взялась из минимально возможной длины в 5 слов. в них входят обязательные поля заголовка. от версии и до адреса назначения. А число 15 - максимальное значение, которое кодируется 4 битами.